# How do I make days clickable in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

How do you turn the white space in the calendar cells into a clickable object which directs you to another page with the cells parameters (e.g. the Date)?

I am building a booking app where i want the user to be able to click a day using FullCalendar to open a booking form which then contains the date.

I've seen a few posts about using a pop up but this isn't what I want.

These are my current configuration settings.

```
function setupCalendar() {
  var calendar_config = {
    firstDay: 1, // Monday
    weekMode: "liquid",
    events: bookingEvents, // this can be a JSON feed (extra HTTP request)
    header: headerOptions,
    selectable: true
  };
  var jq_target_div = $('#calendar');
  jq_target_div.fullCalendar(calendar_config);
}

$(document).ready(setupCalendar);
```

Comment: you need to add more code than this. But if you already have achieved to output the clickable links, simply apply a `display:block` property to those links

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch [dayClickcallback](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/).

Then, you will receive a date parameter as a moment.
From doc:

> **date** holds a Moment for the clicked day. If an all-day area has been
>   clicked, the moment will be ambiguously-timed. If a slot in the
>   agendaWeek or agendaDay views has been clicked, date will have the
>   slot's time.

So finally you just need to open your new form -however you want: in a dialog, in a modal, in a new div... It will depends on your code.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        openNewForm(date);

    }
});
```

In order to clarify your code, I would add in your fullCalendar config a call to your method. So, based on your config...

```
var calendar_config = {
    firstDay: 1, // Monday
    weekMode: "liquid",
    events: bookingEvents, // this can be a JSON feed (extra HTTP request)
    header: headerOptions,
    selectable: true, 
    dayClick: openNewForm   //here is where you redirect the callback
  };

function openNewForm(date, jsEvent, view){
    openNewForm(date);
}
```

Comment: Hey Mario, this is leading me the right direction, and perhaps answered my question. The only thing is how do I open this new form (i want to be redirected to the relevant page)

Comment: The way of open a new form will depend on the structure of your app, which I don't know. The most basic is to put your value in an attribute and submit the current form. You have a demo here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp